# How does one choose which factors to weight on?

Tags: weighted-data, survey-sampling

How does one choose which factors to weight on?

The context is the following: I am running a satisfaction survey. The key outcome metric is satisfaction. The survey has moderate to significant under-
or over-sampling for one or two demographic / usage characteristics and has some minor sampling bias for a few other demographic characteristics.

I'll focus in on two examples to help provide context. 1 - In our population, 23% of individuals are over 65, whereas in our sample, about 35% of individuals are over 65; (2) In terms of estimated household income, there are also slight sampling biases -- there's about a 2% difference between the sample and population across around 10 income brackets. However, I also have access to a whole host of other demographic / usage characteristics (e.g., own a home vs. rent a home, use / don't use certain services offered, etc.) There are potentially 40 different factors I could consider to weight on.

My questions are: (1) how does one choose which factors to weight on or not weight on? (2) how does one decide whether or not it's worth it to include more and more factors into the weighting model ("multivariate weighting")? Specifically, when / how can you tell when adding additional factors has diminishing returns due to the additional error the weighting itself introduces?

To answer question 1 - choosing which factors to weight on -- my thought was to perform the following analysis. First -- look for significant differences in satisfaction between segments (individuals at different levels) of each independent variable (e.g., age, income, etc.) -- if there is no significant difference, then I was going to not consider / include that independent variable in the weighting model. Second -- for each demographic factor in which a significant difference is observed between different levels of the independent variable, I was going to measure the effect size and basically treat the effect size as a measure of how "important" it would be to weight data based on that particular characteristic.

For question 2 - how does one decide whether or not it's worth it to include more and more factors into the weighting model ("multivariate weighting") - I'm really not sure. Note that this is a large sample size study and each level of each independent variable I'm considering weighting on has at least 50 records and up to several hundred.

The very last question has to do with the fact that there are technically several key outcome variables -- essentially, satisfaction with different aspects of a service / experience. Would using a method that predicts which of many predictor variables that are nominal, ordinal, or scale have the most impact on one outcome variable (multiple regression) or several outcome variables (generalized linear model, I think (?)) be a good or better way of determining which factors to weight on rather than what I describe above -- using effect sizes as a way to rank the importance?

Thanks in advance for reading and for your input.